# Using $_GET to Pass Member id

Tags: php, mysql, membership

Im having a problem when trying to create a member login system where each user is directed to their own editable profile. I'm at the login stage right now, and trying to pass the user's id securely from the login page to their profile page so that I can display their profile information.

Right now, I am being redirected to 'mydomain.com/index.php?test=Resource%20id%20#8', (I want, for example 'mydomain.com/index.php?test=1111') after this chunk of code:

```
$user_id = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$user' AND `active`='1'");  
header("location: profile.php?test='$user_id'");
exit();
```

where $user has been sanitized using trim, htmlspecialchars, and mysql_real_escape_string. After the user arrives at 'profile.php,' I am planning on implementing something like this after I can figure out how to properly pass the user id:

```
$user_id=(int)$_GET['$user_id'];
mysql_real_escape_string($user_id);
if (isset($user_id)) {
   $user_id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $user_id); // filter everything but numbers
```

There is more to the code, but I believe I have included all relevant information. Any advice, wisdom, thoughts, and comments are always very much appreciated. Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: I think you intend to leave out the `$` here: `(int)$_GET['$user_id']`

Comment: Just a note. Are you also storing the user id in a session variable? You should do that and verify the user id from the session varible instead of trusting the the user id assed on the url.

What is to stop someone from ediing the address bar and typing in another user id there, allowing them to see and edit other user's profile.

Comment: @iWantSimpleLife thank you very much. I have stored the user id as a session variable at login. Is it sufficient to verify that an unencrypted session variable equals the $_GET value which equals the user id in the database, or do i need to secure the session variable with encryption to pass it securely between multiple pages? Thanks again to everyone who has responded.

Comment: Hi Nick, technically, the session variable is stored on the server and is only accessable on the server. For a simple application, you do not need to encrypt the session variables. Now, if you use a cookie, then that is a different story....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot query and get the result right away.

Try to fix above part as like this.

```
$user_id = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$user' AND `active`='1'");
$user_id = mysql_result($user_id, 0, 'id');  
header("location: profile.php?test='$user_id'");
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is terrible.

1. `isset` is pointless, `$user_id` is always set there.
2. `preg_replace` is pointless - after `(int)` only numbers will be in variable
3. `mysql_real_escape_string` is pointless - after `(int)` there will be no bad characters

So replace that whole block with single line

```
$user_id = isset($_GET['user_id']) ? (int)$_GET['user_id'] : 0;
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that the spec explicitly states POST should be used for actions and GET should be considered safe (in terms of actions.)

Comment: All true, and yet none of it related to the problem (admittedly, the question kind of buries the lead).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Obviously $_GET is a new concept to me. Thanks for helping elaborate

Comment: You can send bigger data with $_POST also.

Comment: @John Flatness: to be clear I don't see any specific question, I see only "Any advice, wisdom, thoughts, and comments are always very much appreciated."

Comment: @zerkms: yet the problem was easily solved. Language is a magical entity. thanks again.

Comment: @zerkms RFC 2616 section 9 http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html . OP mentioned he was working on something that preforms an action.

Comment: @NickB Zerkms has a valid point. Don't be quick to dismiss what he's telling you because he started off with "your code is terrible," rather, figure out why he's saying that.

Comment: @Incognito: oh, good point. I've even forgotten it is specified in RFC, but it is just RFC ;-) Not a law, but advices. Anyway, I agree with you.

Comment: Thanks. I realize that the code is not great. I appreciate all of the help that has been provided to improve it.